# Http ping with fsocket

Tags: php, sockets, http

I want to send a request (POST or GET) and don't wait for answer

I have the code:

```
    $fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://requestb.in:80", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT);

    $out = "GET /15b3x0v1 HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: requestb.in\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fputs($fp, $out);

    //usleep(500);
    fflush($fp);
    fclose($fp);
```

Without the usleep, it doesn't work (the server doesn't receive the request). Why have i to wait 500ms before close the socket ?

Comment: try `fflush` before `fclose`

Comment: Doesn't work with fflush ;)

Comment: How did you check that the server did not *receive* the request? I could imagine that it actually received the request but did not process it since the client has already closed the socket and thus processing it would not be necessary since the client is not expecting a response.

Comment: Cannot really be sure :/ The best way would be to let the socket open, and close it some time later ?